# RichFaces rich:collapsibleSubTable not loading results via ajax

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I am trying to populate a rich:collapsalbeSubTable via a paramatized ajax method call.

The aim is to display a list of customers, when a customer is selected an ajax call has to be made to load the contract list to fill the sub table.

```
<rich:dataTable value="#{searchController.results}" var="customer">

    <rich:column colspan="2">
        <rich:collapsibleSubTableToggler for="contractSubTable" />
        <h:outputText value="#{customer.name}" />
    </rich:column>

    <rich:collapsibleSubTable
        value="#{searchController.getFirstTenContracts(customer.partnerId)}"
        var="contract" id="contractSubTable" expanded="false"
        expandMode="ajax">

        <rich:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{contract.contractId}" />
        </rich:column>
        <rich:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{contract.contractDesc}" />
        </rich:column>

    </rich:collapsibleSubTable>

</rich:dataTable>
```

However this results in the follwing exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.el.ELResolver.invoke(Ljavax/el/ELContext;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:221)
    de.hglv.ebusiness.core.presentation.listener.DisableUrlSessionFilter.doFilter(DisableUrlSessionFilter.java:79)



root cause 

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.el.ELResolver.invoke(Ljavax/el/ELContext;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:111)
    com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:163)
    com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:219)
    org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareTagValueExpression.getValue(ContextAwareTagValueExpression.java:94)
    javax.faces.component._DeltaStateHelper.eval(_DeltaStateHelper.java:246)
    org.richfaces.component.UISequence.getValue(UISequence.java:175)
    org.richfaces.component.UISequence.createExtendedDataModel(UISequence.java:109)
    org.richfaces.component.UIDataTableBase.createExtendedDataModel(UIDataTableBase.java:231)
    org.richfaces.component.UIDataAdaptor.getExtendedDataModel(UIDataAdaptor.java:459)
    org.richfaces.component.UIDataAdaptor.getRowCount(UIDataAdaptor.java:506)
    org.richfaces.renderkit.AbstractTableRenderer.encodeTableRows(AbstractTableRenderer.java:131)
    org.richfaces.renderkit.AbstractTableRenderer.doEncodeChildren(AbstractTableRenderer.java:195)
    org.richfaces.renderkit.RendererBase.encodeChildren(RendererBase.java:157)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:508)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:674)
    org.richfaces.renderkit.DataTableRenderer.encodeRow(DataTableRenderer.java:229)
    org.richfaces.renderkit.AbstractRowsRenderer.process(AbstractRowsRenderer.java:80)
    org.ajax4jsf.model.SequenceDataModel.walk(SequenceDataModel.java:65)
    org.richfaces.component.UIDataAdaptor.walk(UIDataAdaptor.java:796)
    org.richfaces.renderkit.AbstractRowsRenderer.encodeRows(AbstractRowsRenderer.java:90)
    org.richfaces.renderkit.AbstractRowsRenderer.processRows(AbstractRowsRenderer.java:103)
    org.richfaces.renderkit.AbstractTableRenderer.encodeTableRows(AbstractTableRenderer.java:141)
    org.richfaces.renderkit.AbstractTableRenderer.doEncodeChildren(AbstractTableRenderer.java:195)
    org.richfaces.renderkit.RendererBase.encodeChildren(RendererBase.java:157)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:508)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:674)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:681)
    org.richfaces.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:276)
    org.richfaces.renderkit.html.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:181)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:539)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:685)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:681)
    org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.renderView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:1695)
    org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:281)
    javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:59)
    org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk.application.ResourceViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ResourceViewHandlerWrapper.java:93)
    javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:59)
    org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:90)
    org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:239)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:191)
    de.hglv.ebusiness.core.presentation.listener.DisableUrlSessionFilter.doFilter(DisableUrlSessionFilter.java:79)

)
    de.hglv.ebusiness.core.presentation.listener.DisableUrlSessionFilter.doFilter(DisableUrlSessionFilter.java:79)
```

The Signature of the Controller method is:

```
public List<Contract> getFirstTenContracts(Object partnerId)
```

Can some one please help me fix this or point me in the right direction if there is something wrong with my approach.

Comment: Is this all of the stacktrace?

Comment: Sorry, should have posted the whole stacktrace straight away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` gives the problem away:

Your method signature has an argument of type `Object` and you're passing in what I assume to be an `int`. Even in plain old java, this will fail compilation.

Simply change the method signature and you'll be fine

Comment: It is long data type, however I have already tried long, Long and as you can tell Object all with the same result...

Comment: @dngfng then this is most likely because your version of EL does not support the type of method expressions that takes an argument. What app server and JSF/EL distribution are you using? This argument based EL was introduced in 2.2

Comment: we are using el-api 2.2 with JSF 2.1 on Tomcat 6, el-api was the first thing I checked.

Comment: @dngfng tomcat 6 ships with *jsp-api.jar* (and other JSP 2.1 related jars). So make sure you rid your app server installation of any 2.1 related jars and restart your app server.